# Changing the fonts inside a table cell to Source Sans Pro

Tags: html, html-table, fonts, font-style

I want to change all the font inside the table to Source Sans Pro
for a website that I'm working on. I'm not really an expert in HTML and I just need help on changing the font.

```html
<table id="view_bottom_specs" border="1" cellpadding="15px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span class="text-600">OM139-B Binocular Compound Microscope</span></td>
<td><img class="ls-is-cached lazyloaded" title="" src="https://www.microscope.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/m/omano_139b_infinity_corrected_compound_binocular_microscope_main__2.png" alt="" width="100" data-src="https://www.microscope.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/m/omano_139b_infinity_corrected_compound_binocular_microscope_main__2.png" data-original-title="" /><br /><span class="text-600">OM139-BL LED Binocular Compound Microscope</span></td>
<td><img class=" ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="https://www.microscope.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/m/omano_om139t_infinity_corrected_compound_trinocular_microscope_main.png" alt="" width="100" data-src="https://www.microscope.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/m/omano_om139t_infinity_corrected_compound_trinocular_microscope_main.png" /><br /><span class="text-600">OM139-T Trinocular Compound Microscope</span></td>
<td><img class=" ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="https://www.microscope.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/m/omano_om139t_infinity_corrected_compound_trinocular_microscope_main_2.png" alt="" width="100" data-src="https://www.microscope.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/m/omano_om139t_infinity_corrected_compound_trinocular_microscope_main_2.png" /><br /><span class="text-600">OM139-TL LED Trinocular Compound Microscope</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br /><strong><span class="text-600">General</span></strong><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><br /><span class="text-600">Brand</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Omano</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Explorer</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Omano</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Omano</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">SKU</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">OM139-B</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">OM139-BL</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">OM139-T</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">OM139-TL</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Warranty</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Omano Limited Lifetime Warranty</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Omano Limited Lifetime Warranty</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Omano Limited Lifetime Warranty</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Omano Limited Lifetime Warranty</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Magnification Chart</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">MAP Copy</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">None</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><span class="text-600">System</span><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">System Type</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Optical Design</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Infinity Corrected</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Infinity Corrected</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Infinity Corrected</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Infinity Corrected</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br /><strong><span class="text-600">Head</span></strong><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Head Type</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Binocular</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Binocular</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Trinocular</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Trinocular</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Ocular Angle</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30&deg;</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30&deg;</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30&deg;</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30&deg;</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Diopter Adjustment</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Single</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Single</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Single</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Single</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Interpupillary Adjustment</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Arc (Seidentopf)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Arc (Seidentopf)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Arc (Seidentopf)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Arc (Seidentopf)</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Interpupillary Adjustment Range</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">55-75 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">55-75 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">55-75 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">55-75 mm</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Trinocular Tube Focusable?</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Parfocal</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Ocular Tube Diameter</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">30 mm</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br /><strong><span class="text-600">Body</span></strong><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Nosepiece Orientation</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Reversed</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Reversed</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Reversed</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Reversed</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Nosepiece Style</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Quadruple (4)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Quadruple (4)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Quadruple (4)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Quadruple (4)</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Focus Controls</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Coarse &amp; Fine, Coaxial</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Coarse &amp; Fine, Coaxial</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Coarse &amp; Fine, Coaxial</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Coarse &amp; Fine, Coaxial</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Focus Mechanism</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Rack &amp; Pinion</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Rack &amp; Pinion</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Rack &amp; Pinion</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Rack &amp; Pinion</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Focus Control Location</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Dual Ambidextrous</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Dual Ambidextrous</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Dual Ambidextrous</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Dual Ambidextrous</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Focus Controls Graduated?</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Stage Type</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Mechanical XY</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Mechanical XY</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Mechanical XY</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Mechanical XY</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Stage Features</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Fingertip Controls, Slide Holder (spring-loaded)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Fingertip Controls, Slide Holder (spring-loaded)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Fingertip Controls, Slide Holder (spring-loaded)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Fingertip Controls, Slide Holder (spring-loaded)</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Stage Range Graduated?</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br /><strong><span class="text-600">Configuration</span></strong><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Includes Eyepieces?</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Yes</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Yes</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Yes</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Yes</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Included Eyepiece Quantity</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">2</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">2</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">2</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Included Eyepieces (X)</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">10X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">10X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">10X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">10X</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Eyepiece Style</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">SWF Super Widefield (FN 20mm)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">SWF Super Widefield (FN 20mm)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">SWF Super Widefield (FN 20mm)</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">SWF Super Widefield (FN 20mm)</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Includes Eyecups?</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Min Standard Mag</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">40X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">40X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">40X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">40X</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Max Standard Mag</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1000X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1000X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1000X</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1000X</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br /><strong><span class="text-600">Objectives</span></strong><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Included Objectives (Qty)</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">4</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">4</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">4</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Objective Lens</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Plan</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Plan</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Plan</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Plan</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Included Objective Types</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Brightfield</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Included Objectives Parfocal Adjustable?</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><span class="text-600">Condenser</span><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Condenser Type</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Abbe Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Abbe Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Abbe Brightfield</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Abbe Brightfield</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Condenser Features</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Iris Diaphragm, Rack &amp; Pinion Focus, Swing-out Filter Holder</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Iris Diaphragm, Rack &amp; Pinion Focus, Swing-out Filter Holder</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Iris Diaphragm, Rack &amp; Pinion Focus, Swing-out Filter Holder</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Iris Diaphragm, Rack &amp; Pinion Focus, Swing-out Filter Holder</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Condenser N.A.</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1.25 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1.25 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1.25 mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">1.25 mm</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br /><strong><span class="text-600">Illumination</span></strong><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Illumination Type</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Halogen</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">LED</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Halogen</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">LED</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Illumination Style</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Transmitted</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Transmitted</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Transmitted</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Transmitted</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Collector Type</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Kohler</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Kohler</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Kohler</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Kohler</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Collector Features</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Field Diaphragm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Field Diaphragm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Field Diaphragm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Field Diaphragm</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Transmitted Light Type</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Halogen</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">LED</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Halogen</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">LED</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Transmitted Light Specification</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">6V 30W</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">3W</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">6V 30W</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">3W</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Transmitted Light Control</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Variable</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Variable</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Variable</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Variable</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Power Supply</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">85V -265VAC Auto-Switching</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">85V -265VAC Auto-Switching</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">85V -265VAC Auto-Switching</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">85V -265VAC Auto-Switching</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><br /><strong><span class="text-600">Reticles</span></strong><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Reticles Available?</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><span class="text-600">Accessories</span><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Included Extras</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Spare Bulb, Spare Fuse, Dust Cover</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Spare Bulb, Spare Fuse, Dust Cover</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Spare Bulb, Spare Fuse, Dust Cover</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">Spare Bulb, Spare Fuse, Dust Cover</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Case Included?</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">No</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><strong><br /><span class="text-600">Compatibility</span><br /></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="attribute"><span class="text-600">Imaging Compatibility (with adapters</span><br /><br /></td>
<td><span class="text-600">-</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">-</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">23mm</span></td>
<td><span class="text-600">23mm</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I want the text inside the cells to be Source Sans Pro. Is there anyway I can do it with one command? rather than putting it in each ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste style tag inside the body tag. This will change the font inside the td.

```html
<body>

<style>    
td{ font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
</style>

</body>
```